# Fastest Anti-Virus for gaming

Tags: anti-virus

I am a gamer who used to use Norton 360 but realized that it uses a lot of resources. I am looking for something more lightweight. I was wondering whether to use Kapersky or bitdefender. My main concern is speed and reliability. Thanks.

Comment: Malwarebytes, windows defender bundled with a bit of common sense is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number one thing that people seem to forget about anti-virus is that the user is usually the biggest defense against viruses and malware. That being said, Malware bytes combined with Windows Defender is a great, low-resource using bundle. A lot of people involved in computers use that setup and it's highly suggested seeing that its both free and easy to setup.